# C++ erasing section of vector with a size_t as start point

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, type-conversion, warnings

I want to erase a section of a `std::vector` e.g `i`th element through `end`. Where `i` is a `std::size_t` that is calculated beforehand.

```
auto i = vec.size();

for (auto pos = vec.size(); pos > 0; --pos) {
  auto& elem = vec.at(pos - 1);

  if (*magic_condition*) {
    --i;
  }
}

vec.erase(vec.begin() + i, vec.end());
```

I get a `Conversion may change the sign of the result` warning

I tried using `std::next` but that still results in the same warning

The only why I found that gets rid of the warning, but I think is very unelegant is

```
const auto begin = typename decltype(vec)::const_iterator{vec.data() + i};

vec.erase(begin, vec.end());
```

Is there any good solution to get rid if this warning?

**EDIT:**

```
void update(const delta_type delta) {
  auto size = handlers.size();

  for(auto itr = handlers.rbegin(); itr != handlers.rend(); ++itr) {
    auto& handler = *itr;

    if(const auto dead = handler.update(handler, delta); dead) {
      std::swap(handler, handlers.at(--size));
    }
  }

  handlers.erase(handlers.begin() + size, handlers.end());
}
```

Results in following error

```
../ecs/scheduler.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void sbx::scheduler<Delta>::update(sbx::scheduler<Delta>::delta_type) [with Delta = float; sbx::scheduler<Delta>::delta_type = float]’:
/home/kabelitzj/Dev/sandbox/sandbox/core/engine.cpp:39:29:   required from here
../ecs/scheduler.hpp:64:39: warning: conversion to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<sbx::scheduler<float>::process_handler*, std::vector<sbx::scheduler<float>::process_handler, std::allocator<sbx::scheduler<float>::process_handler> > >::difference_type’ {aka ‘long int’} from ‘long unsigned int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   64 |     handlers.erase(handlers.begin() + size, handlers.end());
      |
```

Compiled with `g++ version 9.3.0` and `c++17`

Comment: *Where* do you get this warning? Is the coded you show a proper [mre]?

Comment: no warning here: https://godbolt.org/z/TKh1Erdrq. Please also add the complete warning message.

Comment: OT: `for(auto iter = vec.rbegin(); iter != vec.rend(); ++iter)` is the canonical way to write a loop going down.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have updated the question accordingly, taking into account the answers so far

Comment: The warning is not from the code you posted

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But the warning clearly points to the line were I call erase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown is perfectly fine, AFAICS.  The warning implies that the `vector`'s implementation is in the wrong, not you.  A `vector::iterator` can be incremented by an index, and your index variable is the same type that `vector` uses for its indexes.  So there should be no conversion.  But there is, because the `difference_type` of the iterator is not the same type as the `size_type` of the `vector`.

In any case, this kind of code is unnecessary anyway.  You could just use the [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) via [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)+[`vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), or [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) in C++20. Then there would be no need to handle these kinds of loops and swaps manually at all.  For example:

```cpp
vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(vec.begin, vec.end(),
        [](auto &elem){ return *magic_condition*; }
    ),
    vec.end()
);
```

```cpp
std::erase_if(vec, [](auto &elem){ return *magic_condition*; });
```

```cpp
void update(const delta_type delta) {
  handlers.erase(
    std::remove_if(handlers.begin(), handlers.end(),
      [&](auto &handler){ return (bool) handler.update(handler, delta); }
    ),
    handlers.end()
  );
}
```

```cpp
void update(const delta_type delta) {
  std::erase_if(handlers, [&](auto &handler){ return (bool) handler.update(handler, delta); });
}
```